# quotacheck: Cannot stat() given mountpoint –cugv: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, debian, ext4, quota

I am trying to enable quotas on an ext4 partition of a Debian 9 VM.

The partition is mounted on `/public` with the `usrquota,grpquota` options. The machine has been rebooted.

Here is what happens:

```
root@deb9-fs ~# df -hT /public/
Filesystem     Type  Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda4      ext4  4.4G   18M  4.1G   1% /public
root@deb9-fs ~#
root@deb9-fs ~# mount | grep public
/dev/sda4 on /public type ext4 (rw,relatime,quota,usrquota,grpquota,data=ordered)
root@deb9-fs ~# touch /public/test
root@deb9-fs ~# ll /public/
total 16K
drwx------ 2 root root 16K Jan 24 10:46 lost+found/
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   0 Jan 24 23:13 test
root@deb9-fs ~# quotacheck –cugv /public
quotacheck: Cannot stat() given mountpoint –cugv: No such file or directory
Skipping...
quotacheck: No correct mountpoint specified.
quotacheck: Cannot initialize mountpoint scan.
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Aliased?  What does `which quotacheck` show?

Comment: It does not seem so:

`root@deb9-fs ~# which quotacheck`
`/sbin/quotacheck`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You copied and pasted a Unicode character that looks like a hyphen, but is not actually.

The character you pasted was `–`, which an en dash.

The actual character you should be using is `-`, which is a plain hyphen as it appears on your keyboard.

This is an error in whatever tutorial you were reading. Some content management systems change hyphens into Unicode dashes if they aren't properly escaped in that CMS's editor.